# ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Invalid Token Randomly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

Sometimes users get Invalid Token when clicking on their email confirmation link. I can't figure out why, it's purely random.

Here is the code that creates the user:

```
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, "Password134567");
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("WebApp2015");
    UserManager<User> userManager = new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>());
    userManager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create(user.Id));
    manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("ConfirmUser"));

    var emailInfo = new Email();

    string code = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Context.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id));
    string callbackUrl = IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl(code, user.Id, Request);

    if (email.IndexOf("@") != -1)
    {
        if (assignedId == 0)
        {
            lblError.Text = "There was an error adding this user";
            return;
        }
        string emailcontent = emailInfo.GetActivationEmailContent(assignedId, callbackUrl, userRole);
        string subject = emailInfo.Subject;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(subject))
        {
            subject = "Your Membership";
        }
        Context.GetOwinContext()
               .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
               .SendEmail(user.Id, subject, emailcontent);

        if (user.EmailConfirmed)
        {
            IdentityModels.IdentityHelper.SignIn(manager, user, isPersistent: false);
            IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"], Response);
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMessage.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            ErrorMessage.Text = "An email has been sent to the user, once they verify their email they are ready to login.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ErrorMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        ErrorMessage.Text = "User has been created.";
    }

    var ra = new RoleActions();
    ra.AddUserToRoll(txtEmail.Text, txtEmail.Text, userRole);
}
else
{
    ErrorMessage.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here is the confirmation page that gives the 'invalid token' error

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var code = IdentityHelper.GetCodeFromRequest(Request);
    var userId = IdentityHelper.GetUserIdFromRequest(Request);
    if (code != null && userId != null)
    {
        var manager = Context.GetOwinContext()
                             .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        var confirmId = manager.FindById(userId);
        if (confirmId != null)
        {
            var result = manager.ConfirmEmail(userId, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code));
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                lblError.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                txtNewPassword.TextMode= TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                txtNewPassword.Text = "Error contact support";
                txtNewPassword2.TextMode= TextBoxMode.SingleLine;
                txtNewPassword2.Text = result.Errors.FirstOrDefault();
                txtNewPassword.Enabled = false;
                txtNewPassword2.Enabled = false;
                imageButton1.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Account Does Not Exist";
            imageButton1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the conformation link look like?  Are you doing a redirect or is it a click event?

Comment: Start logging tokens created and tokens requested, success and failures, to see what the differences are.  This may give a hint to what is going on.

Comment: Have you verified that the link being used by the user is a fully valid link? Email is notorious for breaking up text blocks, and several email clients mark up processes will create a link from broken reference links. This means a user will often have the correct base URL, but a broken parameter or token being passed in.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Live Demo Project

I've created a pared-down demo project for you. It's hosted on [GitHub here](https://github.com/bigfont/AspNetIdentityEmailToken) and is live on [Azure here](http://identity-email-token.azurewebsites.net/). It works as designed (see edits about Azure Websites) and uses a similar but not identical approach as you used.

It started with [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity), and then I removed the cruft that came with this NuGet demo code:

```
Install-Package -Prerelease Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples
```

For your purposes, [my demo code](https://github.com/bigfont/AspNetIdentityEmailToken) is more relevant than the NuGet sample is, because it focuses just on token creation and validation. In particular, take a look at these two files:

### [Startup.Auth.cs](https://github.com/bigfont/AspNetIdentityEmailToken/blob/master/AspNetIdentityEmailToken/App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs).

We're instantiating the `IDataProtectionProvider` only once per application start.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static IDataProtectionProvider DataProtectionProvider 
    { 
        get; 
        private set; 
    }

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        DataProtectionProvider = 
            new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("WebApp2015");

        // other code removed
    }
}
```

### [AccountController.cs](https://github.com/bigfont/AspNetIdentityEmailToken/blob/master/AspNetIdentityEmailToken/Controllers/AccountController.cs).

Then within the `AccountController`, we're using the static provider instead of creating a new one.

```
userManager.UserTokenProvider = 
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(
        Startup.DataProtectionProvider.Create("UserToken"));
```

Just doing that might remove the bug you're seeing. Here are some questions for you to consider while troubleshooting further.

## Are you using two different `UserTokenProvider` purposes?

The `DataProtectorTokenProvider.Create(string[] purposes)` method takes a `purposes` argument. Here is what MSDN has to say about that:

> purposes. Additional entropy used to ensure protected data may only be unprotected for the correct purposes.

When you create the user `code`, you're using (at least) two different purposes:

1. `user.Id`
2. `"ConfirmUser"` and
3. the purpose of the  `ApplicationUserManager` that you retrieve with `GetOwinContext()...`.

Here's your code as a snippet.

```
userManager.UserTokenProvider = 
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create(user.Id));

manager.UserTokenProvider = 
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("ConfirmUser"));

string code = Context
    .GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager ()      
    .GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id)
```

When you validate the `code`, you might be using the wrong purpose. Where do you assign the `UserTokenProvider` for the `ApplicationUserManager` that you use to confirm the email? It's purposes argument must be the same!

```
var manager = Context.GetOwinContext()
                  .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

var result = manager.ConfirmEmail(userId, HttpUtility.UrlDecode(code));
```

There is a strong chance that the token is invalid because you're *sometimes* using a different `UserTokenProvider` purpose for creation than you're using for validation.

Why would this be sometimes? Do a thorough search of your code to find all the places that assign to `UserTokenProvider`. Maybe you override it somewhere unexpected (such as in a property or in the IdentityConfig.cs file) so that it seems random.

## Has the `TokenLifespan` expired?

You've mentioned that the Invalid Token message occurs randomly. It might be that the token has expired. [This tutorial](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity) notes that the default lifespan is one day. You can change it like this:

```
manager.UserTokenProvider = 
    new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
      (dataProtectionProvider.Create("WebApp2015"))
      {                    
         TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(3000)
      };
```

## Why three `UserManager` instances?

Here are some comments on the code that creates the confirmation token. It seems that you're using a three separate `UserManager` instances including a derived `ApplicationUserManager` type. What's that about?

1. What is the type of `manager` here?
2. Why create a `userManager` instead of using the existing `manager`?
3. Why use `manager.UserTokenProvider` not `userManager.UserTokenProvider`?
4. Why are you getting a third `UserManager` instance from the `Context`?

Note that I have removed a lot of code to focus on just your token creation.

```
// 1. 
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, "Password134567");

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("WebApp2015");

    // 2. 
    UserManager<User> userManager = 
        new UserManager<User>(new UserStore<User>());

    userManager.UserTokenProvider = 
        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create(user.Id));

    // 3.
    manager.UserTokenProvider = 
        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create("ConfirmUser"));

    // 4. 
    string raw = Context.GetOwinContext()
                 .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
                 .GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id)

    // remaining code removed
}
```

I wonder whether we could simplify the above to use just one `UserManager` instance as follows.

```
// 1. 
IdentityResult result = manager.Create(user, "Password134567");

if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var provider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("WebApp2015");

    manager.UserTokenProvider = 
        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider.Create(user.Id));

    // 3.
    var provider = provider.Create("ConfirmUser");
    manager.UserTokenProvider = 
        new DataProtectorTokenProvider<User>(provider);

    // 4. 
    string raw = manager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken(user.Id);

    // remaining code removed
}
```

If you use this approach, be sure to use the same `"ConfirmUser"` purposes argument during confirmation of the email.

## What's inside `IdentityHelper`?

Since the error is happening randomly, it occurs to me that the `IdentityHelper` methods might be doing something funky to the `code` that mucks up things. What's inside each of these methods?

- `IdentityHelper.GetUserConfirmationRedirectUrl()`
- `IdentityHelper.RedirectToReturnUrl()`
- `IdentityHelper.GetCodeFromRequest()`
- `IdentityHelper.GetUserIdFromRequest()`

I might write some tests to ensure that the raw `code` that your process creates always matches the raw `code` that your process retrieves from the `Request`. In pseudo-code:

```
var code01 = CreateCode();
var code02 = UrlEncode(code01);
var request = CreateTheRequest(code02);
var response = GetTheResponse();
var code03 = GetTheCode(response);
var code04 = UrlDecode(code03);
Assert.AreEquals(code01, code04);
```

Run the above 10,000 times to ensure that no problems exist.

## Conclusion

It's my strong suspicion that the problem lies in using one `purposes` argument during token creation and another during confirmation. Use one purpose only and you might be fine.

## Making this work on Azure Websites

1. Use SqlCompact instead of localdb.
2. Use `app.GetDataProtectionProvider()` not `DpapiDataProtectionProvider` because Dpapi does not work with web farms.

Comment: Plus 1 for TokenLifespan!

Answer (score 2):

Is the site hosted on multiple web servers?
If so, you cannot use DPAPI here. It is machine-specific.
You'll need to use another data protection provider.

Answer (score 1):

There might be some url-invalid characters in the code (token). Thus we need to use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(token)` and `HttpUtility.UrlDecode(token)` when it appears in any url.

See something details here: 
[Identity password reset token is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617870/identity-password-reset-token-is-invalid)

Comment: Please see more information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25405307/asp-net-identity-2-invalid-token-error/28983864#28983864, there might be more than one token-validators (which might be unnoticed).

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I think Shaun has provided great feedback to resolve such issues. There is one comment you made that makes me think it just might be an Alternate token issue.  See also comments about multiple servers and Tokens.

> ... it's purely random

I dont think its random ;-). But what could make it work much of the time then for some users not.

A token was generated for a different page or APP, or is from the same APP and has just expired. Eg token valid for a short period. Is present in the browser.  The token is from a similar app or from the same app on a different form/page.
The browser present the token since the token was generated for the Domain.

But when analyzed the token didnt match, or just expired.

Consider the lifecycle of the tokens.