# Implementing Forgot Password in ASP.NET Core without using ConfirmEmail

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

As we know when we create an `ASP.NET Core` app with `Individual User Accounts` mode, the Visual Studio template generates some account related code and Views etc. **Question**: When implementing Forgot Password functionality, is Email Confirmation a requirement in ASP.NET Core?

For example in the following `ForgotPassword(...)` Post action  generated by Visual Studio, if `_userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)` is not true the `ResetPassword` link is not generated and email is not sent to the user. I then tried the code by removing `_userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))` from the code below but then, although, the `ResetPassword` link gets generated and an email with that link is successfully sent but I when I click on the link in the email and correctly fill in the `Reset Password` form and submit it, I get the validation error as: `Invalid Token`. In our case there are only four users all of whom were create using Register.cshtml view but we did not use Email confirmation functionality at the time of creating these users. **NOTE**: We're using `ASP.NET Core 1.1.1` with `VS2017`. The code is on the same machine (windows 10) where the email is checked and the generated `Reset Password` link is clicked. The ASPNETUsers table has SecurityStamp value for all four users. So there should probably no SecurityStamp or machineKey related issue on `Invalid Token` error.

**AccountController**

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> ForgotPassword(ForgotPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null || !(await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user)))
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
            return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
        }

        // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532713
        // Send an email with this link
        var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ResetPassword), "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);
        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(model.Email, "Reset Password",
            $"Please reset your password by clicking here: <a href='{callbackUrl}'>link</a>");
        return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: `IsEmailConfirmed` has nothing to do with generating tokens. I suspect you have a problem with tokens and removing that condition is just exposing the issue.

Comment: @Shoe I tend to agree with you. Problem seems to be token related only. For some reason token is not working So I posted the detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46249048/1232087) thinking someone may shed some light on the possible causes of the issue and a possible resolution.

Comment: @nam you can try to create the users directly with EmailConfirmed=true or to update the AspNetUsers table records with EmailConfirmed=true